# wmctrl to open window without focus

Tags: linux, window, focus, gnome

I am using the command:

```
wmctrl -a **id of application** -i
```

This is very close to what I am looking for, however Is there a away I can use wmctrl without bringing focus to the application.

For example if i run the command to bring up a window on my 2nd screen in terminal the focus of the mouse and keyboard stay on terminal.

Answer (score 8):

`xdotool` may come in handy in your situation.

1. You should **save** your active window's `ID` to temporary file:

   `xdotool getactivewindow > ~/.window_id`
2. Then **focus** desired window:

   `wmctrl -a **id of application** -i`
3. And then **restore** focus to the *previous* window:

   `xdotool windowfocus $(cat ~/.window_id)
   xdotool windowactivate $(cat ~/.window_id)`

Using `xbindkeys`, `xdotool` and `wmctrl` combined create a very powerful tool-set.

Comment: This still changes the focus and then brings back!